# Why is _spPageContextInfo.userId different than REST call to currentUser.id ?

Tags: 2013, javascript

Have a question about a user's unqiue id in SP2013: namely, how to get the current user's id via a Javascript REST call.

I have some lists that have a user lookup and the ID stored in this lookup is the same as in `_spPageContextInfo.userId`.  However, when I do a REST call to `https://[mysite]/_api/web/currentUser` I get a different ID.

How do I make a REST call that would get me the same value as `_spPageContextInfo.userId` ?

#### Example

```
_spPageContextInfo.userId === 540 // same value as in List columns

var g = $.ajax({
  url: "https://[mysite]/_api/web/currentUser",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  }
});

p.responseJSON.d.Id === 639  // this is different though 

// why is this?
_spPageContextInfo.userId !== p.responseJSON.d.Id
```

Comment: is [mysite] your current web or different web or site collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using different web (or site) the user Id(s) will differ. Since _api is a virtual folder it can be called from any web. In your case, use the current web. See the snippet below:

```
window.console && console.info('spPageContextInfo user Id: ' + _spPageContextInfo.userId);

function getCurrentWebUrl() {
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    return webUrl.endsWith("/") ? webUrl : webUrl + "/";
}

var p = $.ajax({
    url: getCurrentWebUrl() + "_api/web/currentUser",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
});

p.done(function (data) {
    window.console && console.info('From ajax response: user Id ' + data.d.Id);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the super long delay but I got pulled into another project.  Yes!  Adding the sub-site to the URL fixed the issue.  Thanks so much and glad it was so simple!